# How can I copy a column value from excel to txt file

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm new to Power shell. I have a number of excel files (500+) having a column Animal Count that I would like to save in a new '.txt' file. Can any one give me tips to achieve this.

Comment: Do you mean you need the values in the 'Animal Count' column saved as text, or the whole worksheet?

Comment: I need only Animal Count column Data, The main purpose of this is to check the blank reports. ie., Animal Count is Null in the excel files.

Comment: Please can you show us one of these files (part of). Are you after a summary report on where all numbers in that column total to 0?

Comment: i have added the image for reference

Comment: Thanks Theo, for your help. I need one more logic to be added. I have 1000's of excel files in the folder . but this should scan based on modified date. For example, I have generated reports today, this script should scan excel files which are created today by using Date modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the image you provided, The count value is not in a column called 'Animal count', but in the column next to a **label** with that text.

As for the type of output, I would recommend not to use a .txt file, but output the found info as CSV file to be abe to keep the file names and the animal count values in a structured way.

Try:

```
$Source = 'D:\Test'  # the path to where the Excel files are

# create an Excel COM object
$excel  = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application 

# find Excel files in the Source path and loop through.
# you may want to add the -Recurse switch here if the code should also look inside subfolders
$result = Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -Filter '*.xlsx' -File | ForEach-Object {
    $workBook  = $excel.Workbooks.Open($_.FullName)
    $workSheet = $Workbook.Sheets.Item(1)
    $count     = 0
    $label     = $WorkSheet.Cells.Find('*Animal count*')
    if ($label) {
        # get the numeric value for the cell next to the label
        # empty cells will translate to 0
        $count = [int]$workSheet.Cells.Item($label.Row, $label.Column + 1).Value()
    }
    # output a PSObject with the full filename and the animal count value
    [PsCustomObject] @{
        'File'        = $_.FullName
        'AnimalCount' = $count
    }
    $workBook.Close()
}

# quit Excel and clean up the used COM objects
$excel.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($workSheet) | Out-Null
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($workBook) | Out-Null
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel) | Out-Null
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()


# output on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

#output to CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\AnimalCount.csv' -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
```

The result on screen wil look something like this:

```
File               AnimalCount
----               -----------
D:\Test\File1.xlsx         165
D:\Test\File2.xlsx           0
D:\Test\File3.xlsx       87596
```

---

**Edit**

Since you've commented the labels are in *Merged cells*, you need to use this to find the value for `Animal count`:

```
$label = $workSheet.Range('$A:$B').Find('*Animal count*')

if ($label) {
    # get the numeric value for the cell next to the label
    # empty cells will translate to 0
    $count = [int]$workSheet.Cells.Item($label.Row, $label.Column + 2).Value()
}
```

That is assuming there are two cells merged into one.

<sup>P.S. If the animal count value can ever exceed 2147483647, cast to `[int64]` instead of `[int]`</sup>

Comment: Im getting animal count as 0 for all the files, dont know where im missing. Could you please hep me?

Comment: @NagarajuKukudala Can you check if all files have this label `Animal count:` It must be an **exact match**. BTW Why did you remove the image? It explained very well that the label is in the first column.. Please put that back in.

Comment: Ok, Thanks, The problem here is the Animal Count label is a merged cell, so cells.Find is not picking it. And also  can we achieve this with using com object ?

Comment: The script should be used in production server, so the com object will not work.. could you please help me without using com object. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @NagarajuKukudala I have added new code to find the label in a merged cell. The latest comment is information you should have mentioned in the original question, not **after** it has been answered, because that would take a completely different approach using `OLEDB`.

Comment: Thanks @Theo , My apologies for not mentioning it before. Is there any way that i can get it with out com object?

Comment: @NagarajuKukudala You can try module [Import-Excel](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel)

Comment: Could you please help me in achieving this using OLEDB ?

Comment: @NagarajuKukudala Sorry, that is not really my cup-of-tea, but you can fined examples on how to read xlsx files [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58244399/using-powershell-with-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-to-convert-between-csv-xml-xls-xl) or [here](https://faultqueue.wordpress.com/2016/04/03/convert-xlsx-to-csv-using-powershell/). For connectionstring examples look [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/)

Comment: @NagarajuKukudala P.S. If you don't have Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 installed, you can download it from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255). Select the proper file to match the bitness of your computers architecture. (32 or 64 bit)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Import-Csv to turn the excel file into a PS object, and the columns would be the new object's properties.

```
$excel = Import-Csv $excelPath
$excel.Animals | out-file $txtPath
```

Comment: `Import-Csv` cannot do Excel files.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this this is for 1 file save to txt same name.
this can you done for more file's with foreach options**

```
$FileName = "C:\temp\test.xlsx"
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.visible = $false
$Excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
$WorkBook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($FileName)
$NewFilePath = [System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($FileName,".txt")
$Workbook.SaveAs($NewFilepath, 42)   # xlUnicodeText
  # cleanup
$Excel.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($WorkBook) | Out-Null
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Excel) | Out-Null
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```